# Symfony 3.3 - invalid user token in service

Tags: php, symfony

I have UserPermission service defined as below (UserPermission extends EntityPermission):

```
<service id="permission.user" class="AppBundle\Service\Permission\UserPermission">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />          
</service>
```

The problem is that when I'm using (in EntityPermission):

```
// sc is service_container
$tokenStorage = $this->sc->get('security.token_storage');
```

the result is instance of  Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage

but when i try to get token by

```
$tokenStorage->getToken()
```

it returns instance of AppBundle\Service\Permission\EntityPermission instead of expected object. In profiler everything is OK (user logged, fully authenticated with UsernamePasswordToken).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, now I see that token is just null (and get_class(null) returns current class name). But why is it empty?